# I have some trouble with flask source in logging.py

Tags: python, flask

[logging.py](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/0.10.1/flask/logging.py#L26-L30)

```
class DebugLogger(Logger):
    def getEffectiveLevel(x):
        if x.level == 0 and app.debug:
            return DEBUG
        return Logger.getEffectiveLevel(x)
```

[Logger.getEffectiveLevel](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.getEffectiveLevel) doesn't need any argument.

what does `'x'` mean?

Answer (score 2):

The first argument of a method is an instance object. We all are used to call it `self` but it is not a must.

Comment: It's called `self` in [more recent revisions](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/7f3867491570746a4c14bdaa5bd59ec1b64cbfea/flask/logging.py#L60).